# jQuery File Upload always fails and doesn't attempt to contact server

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to use the jQuery File Upload library by BlueImp to let me upload files to a server with AJAX.  The server is a custom application that returns JSON.  This has been tested and returns a set of JSON objects as expected, when presented with a file.

However, when I add jQuery File Upload and try and either drag-and-drop a file to a dropzone or just use the file upload button, it never makes any attempt to call the server and the `done` function is never called.  I added the `fail` function and it is called every time, but with no `errorThrown` and a `textStatus` of `error`.  A cut down version of my code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<style type="text/css">
.dropzone {
    background: #6cc;
    width: 49%;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    border: 3px dashed #01608d;
}

.bar {
    height: 18px;
    background: #099;
}
</style>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="../static/script/jquery-3.3.1.min.js""></script>
<script src="../static/script/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js""></script>
<script src="../static/script/jquery.iframe-transport.js""></script>
<script src="../static/script/jquery.fileupload.js""></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    init();
});

function init()
{

    // configure the fileupload objects
    $('#fileuploadClasslist').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: true,
        dropZone: $("#fileuploadClasslistContainer"),
        fileInput: $("#fileuploadClasslist"),
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress= parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $("#classlistProgress .bar").css('width', progress + '%');      
        },
        drop: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                console.log('Dropped file: ' + file.name);
            });
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            alert("done!");
            console.log(data.result);
        },
        fail: function (e, data) {
            alert("There was an error:\n" 
                    + "data.errorThrown: " + data.errorThrown + "\n"
                    + "; data.textStatus: " + data.textStatus
            );
        },
    });
} // end function init()
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="fileuploadClasslistContainer" class="dropzone">
    Upload a classlist file
    <input type="file" name="fileuploadClasslist" id="fileuploadClasslist" data-url="http://my.server.com/path/process" multiple/>
    <div id="classlistProgress">
        <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The result of dragging a file on to the dropzone is always:

```
There was an error:
data.errorThrown:
; data.textStatus: error
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Before alert("There was an error:\n" do a console.log(data) to see complete error message in console (developers tool via F12)

Comment: Thanks very much.  This enabled me to find the answer, which, I'm embarrassed to say, was just a CORS issue.  I hadn't realised that file: URLs are counted against CORS and the request to the server was being blocked.  Sorry for wasting everyone's time.